# How do I allow SFTP with a password BUT not SSH?

Tags: 12.04, ftp, sftp

I have SSH keys set up for every user with which they SSH into the proper machines. The problem is that many FTP programs dont support SSH login. Therefore, *only* for FTP do I want to allow users to login with a password. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible answer:

https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh

Link describes the use of

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp